# Upload image name issue when share the social sites Upload plugin in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I am told about Image upload plugin version for **cakephp2.x** not the cakephp3.x

I am using **Upload plugin** for image upload in **cakephp2.x**. It is a nice plugin.

https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack

**Problem:**

If upload image name like `Koala - animal.jpg` plugin stored the name as `<id>_Koala - animal.jpg`
When we **share the image to social site**.

**Image is not sharing the social site due to (image name)space issue.**

So I want store the image name like `<id>_Koala_-_animal.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the **solutions** after one and half days:

Add the **following code** in the following file

```
Upload\Model\Behavior\UploadBehavior.php

public function beforeSave(Model $model,$options=array()) {

    //Existing code

    /*Fixes code before "return true;" start*/
    if(isset($model->data[$model->alias][$field])){
        $model->data[$model->alias][$field] = str_replace(' ','_',$model->data[$model->alias][$field]);
    }
    /*Fixes code before "return true;" End*/

    return true;
}
```